# Setting value in JS, but codebehind doesn't get updated value. ASP.Net

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I'm using bootbox prompt to do validation before saving, in the callback function I'm setting a hiddenfield value and then going into a button click event. But hiddenfield in the C# part doesn't get the value I've set in the JS. How should I fix this?

JS:

```
function notePrompt() {
    var protNumber = $("#hfProtNumberGen").val();
    var hfNote = document.getElementById("<%= hfNote.ClientID %>");
    var btnHidden = document.getElementById('btnHidden');
    if (protNumber != "") {
        bootbox.prompt({
            title: "Въведете причина за промяната. Повърдете запазването на информацията.",
            inputType: 'textarea',
            buttons: {
                confirm: {
                    label: "Запази"
                },
                cancel: {
                    label: "Откажи"
                }
            },
            callback: function (result) {
                if (result == null) {
                    hfNote.value = "";
                }
                else {
                    var MaxLenghtResult = result.slice(0, 200);
                    hfNote.value = MaxLenghtResult;
                    if (hfNote.value != "") {
                        setTimeout(function () { btnHidden.click(); }, 1000);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        setTimeout(function () { btnHidden.click(); }, 1000);
    }
}
```

C#:

```
string Note = hfNote.Value; //always gets ""
```

Comment: is it paure asp.net i.e. not asp.net mvc , right ?

Comment: Please post the aspx page contents and the rendered HTML. My guess is that ASP.NET is changing the Id of the hidden field and you either need to write out the ID of the hidden field or change `getElementById` to get the element some other way.

Comment: can you try to read value like this var value = Request.Form[hfName.UniqueID]; as i updated in my answer

Comment: This is pure ASP.NET not mvc. And Okay @PranayRana I'm testing now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to do like this , means you have to make control runat ="server" and in javascript need to udpate value in control by getting clientid of control

```
//axps file - this seems working for you
<asp:HiddenField ID = "hfName" runat = "server" />

//javascript --- you need to this change 
document.getElementById("<%=hfName.ClientID %>").value = MaxLenghtResult;

//in aspx.cs file 
string note = Request.Form[hfName.UniqueID];
```